# Sending location in same page where action is performed in php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a table which are going in many pages and all table row have one attribute which performing a drop down which showing a button  and after clicking  that button it would delete value in database. Now if i am deleting value from second or any page i want it should remain in same page either it come from page `url` with pagination number or come from page with search key and pagination number
here some code of pagination with search element key

```
 $total_num_page=50;
               if (isset($_GET['page']))
                    {
                        $page_id = $_GET['page'];
                    } 
               else
                    {
                        $page_id = 1;
                    }
                    $search = '' ;
                    if( isset($_POST['search']) )
                    {
                        $search = urldecode($_POST['search']);
                    }
                    else if( isset($_GET['search']) ) 
                    {
                        $search = urldecode($_GET['search']);
                    }


 if ( $search )
              {
                        $all_post_query = "select * from files where recieved_by like '%" . $search . "%' or processed_by like  '%" . $search . "%' or   purpose like  '%" . $search . "%' or file_name like  '%" . $search . "%' order by id desc";
                        $all_post_run = mysqli_query($con, $all_post_query);
                        $all_post = mysqli_num_rows($all_post_run);
                        $total_page = ceil($all_post / $total_num_page);
                        $page_start_from = ($page_id - 1) * $total_num_page;
              } 
               else {
                    $all_post_query = "select * from files order by id desc";
                    $all_post_run = mysqli_query($con, $all_post_query);
                    $all_post = mysqli_num_rows($all_post_run);
                    $total_page = ceil($all_post / $total_num_page);
                    $page_start_from = ($page_id - 1) * $total_num_page;
                    }

               ?>
```

And code of showing page

```
<nav id="pagination">
        <ul class="pagination">
            <?php
            $search_str = '';
            if ($search) {
                $search_str = "&search=" . urlencode($search);
            }
            for ($i = 1; $i <= $total_page; $i++)
                echo "<li class='" . ($page_id == $i ? 'active' : '') . "'><a href='index.php?page=" . $i . $search_str . "'>$i</a></li>";
            ?>

        </ul>

                                           </nav>
```

i want  only when button is clicked and performed j query it should only refresh the page and stay in same page with pagination number and search key, Here is code

```
<?php
                if(isset($_GET['index_edit_id']))
                {
                     $delete_id=$_GET['index_edit_id'];
                     $sql = "DELETE FROM update_table WHERE  id='$delete_id';UPDATE files SET show_status=null  WHERE id='$delete_id';DELETE FROM callcase WHERE id='$delete_id';DELETE FROM lettercase WHERE id='$delete_id'";
                     $run=mysqli_multi_query($con,$sql);
                     header("location:index.php");
                }
?>
```

and jQuery code

```
$(".remove").click(function() {
  var id = $(this).parents("tr").attr("index_edit_id");
  if (confirm('Are you sure you want to edit the action ?')) {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'callfile.php',
      type: 'GET',
      data: {
        id: id
      },
      error: function() {
        alert('Something is wrong');
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $("#" + id).remove();
        alert("Edited action removed successfully");
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Help me Please.

Comment: Leave form action's value blank to achieve this. However, if you've any POST data, you may have to populate the hidden fields with that information.

Comment: @Areeb it is blank sir  , its performing all sequence but after going in location header i want it only refresh the page and stay still in same pagination number if it is also with search key element then it also be in same pagination number and search element key

Comment: At the isset($_GET['index_edit_id'])) block, include the pagination offset, query. Like:

header("location: index.php?search=" . $_GET['search'] . '&page=' . $_GET['page']);

Comment: @Areeb when i am clicking the button it would send only row id , then how could it get page and search key in location header . here is code of button  `<a href="callfile.php?edit_id=<?php echo $id;?>"><button class="btn btn-default   btn-sm remove"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-lg" aria-hidden='true'> Edit</i></button></a>`