# staying in same page using location header in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have table which are going in different pages and all row have one attribute which is button and button is used for deleting row from table and when button function performed , it is going in header action , but when it is performed in second page after completing action header is sending  it in  first page , i want it should stay in same  page. How can i do this?

Here is some code

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['index_edit_id']))
{
    $delete_id=$_GET['index_edit_id'];
    $sql = "DELETE FROM update_table WHERE  id='$delete_id';UPDATE files SET show_status=null  WHERE id='$delete_id';DELETE FROM callcase WHERE id='$delete_id';DELETE FROM lettercase WHERE id='$delete_id'";
    $run=mysqli_multi_query($con,$sql);
    header("location:index.php");
}
?>
```

I want to send location with pagination number and if it is with search key then it should also take all passable situation , should i store key and pagination number in session . Help me please

Answer (score 5):

You Question is not clear
If you want to stay in the page where the code you showed is runing , just delete the last line :  header("location:index.php");
if you want it to go back to the page that called replace this

```
header("location:index.php");
```

with this

```
header("location:".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

If you want to send some parametter , send it with url as id=5
Than replace the id in the header like this

```
header("location:page.php?id=".$_GET['id'));
```

I hope this helped you.

Comment: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47919847/sending-location-in-same-page-where-action-is-performed-in-php> here is link where all code is available .

Comment: Sir when i am sending id for delete then page would get only id from row and page number  would be lost   and then `?id=".$_GET['id']` this code generate error .

Comment: can i store page id number and search key  in session and when user goes in second page and performing  delete function , so it already had stored page number and search key and use to send location at given page number and search key

Comment: You Can actualy send more than one paratemer,like this
if page url is this /delete.php?id=5&pageNumber=10
in the php code get the page number and id like this
$id=$_GET["id"];
$pageNumber=$_GET["pageNumber"];
this is easy method, if you like you can save it in cookies and session,I would recommend the first method or the Cookie method, 
if you find this answer helpful you know what to do .
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand you are using a single table instance which is accessed by multiple other html pages. But what i suggest is you can use ajax function to perform delete operation and then you can just call a function to refresh the table alone

**bellow is my suggestion not the solution**

and here is the php code :

```
<td><p>".$row['STATUS']."</p></td>
        <td><button class='btn btn-outline-danger' id='btn_Delete' onclick='onDelete()' value='".$row['ORDER_ID']."'><i class='fa fa-minus-circle' aria-hidden='true'></i>
 Delete</button>
```

**the ajax code follows here**

```
 var id = $("#btn_Delete").val();
    $.ajax({
            url: "your php link to delete",
            method: "your methios",
            data: {
                REFERENCE_ID: id,
            },
            success: function(result) {
                UIkit.notification({
                    message: result,
                    status: 'primary',
                    pos: 'top-right',
                    timeout: 5000
                });
                showTable();
            }
        })
        .done(function() {
            console.log("success");
        })
        .fail(function() {
            console.log("error");
        })
        .always(function() {
            console.log("complete");
        });
```

once done i have called the showtable() function which will automatically refresh the table in the html page without redirecting to another page

**This might help you..**

Answer (score 0):

use javascript code for refresh page :

```
    location.href += ""
```

or php location to current page